# The right SQL or ActiveRecord formulation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's the scenario. I have a database called sentiment_log which records real time 'votes' from students, attending a certain lecture, who vote at a specific time that they are "engaged" or "confused". The lecture is divided into time slots denoted by an integer. The schema looks like this:

```
student_id: int
sentiment_id: int
lecture_id: int
time_slot: int
```

The rails model is SentimentLog I believe what I want can be done in a single bit of clever SQL but I have not succeeded in formulating it. What I want is, given a target_time_slot and a target_lecture_id, result set with a record per student_id, like this:

- student_id
- the sentiment_id recorded in the most recent time slot that the student_id voted

So something like,

- select a subset of records with `lecture_id == target_lecture_id` and `time_slot <= target_time_slot`
- select from that a subset of records where each student is represented by their most recent (i.e. greatest) `time_slot`.

This should yield a single record per `student_id`.

I've not been successful so far.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us your model name, so I'll call it "Foo". I also assume that everything is in that same table. You don't describe student_id, is it the same as user_id?

```
@foos=Foo.where("lecture_id = ? AND time_slot <= ?",target_lecture_id, target_time_slot).maximum(:time_slot, group: :student_id)
```

This statement will provide a hash like:

```
{4=>240, 5=>235, 2=>237, 1=>243, 3=>241} #{:student_id => max(:time_slot)}
```

Result usage example:

```
@foos.each do |foo|
    puts foo[0] #... (student_id)
    puts foo[1] #... (max time_slot)
end
```

Comment: Sorry, the model is called SentimentLog and student_id is what it should be, the user_id was a typo, which I will correct. And thanks! I will try it out :)